# New version jQuery doesn't work, but old version works

Tags: jquery, .net

I am working on an existing legacy .net web form project with jQuery v1.7.2 (not from package manager). I downloaded new version 3.1.1 from package manager. I comment out the reference on the page to 1.7.2 and add a new reference to the new version. However, the Scripts stop working. I add back the old version, and the Scripts starting working again. It seems the system only recognise the old version.
Do anyone know what happened? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have issues with some existing jquery code that you have. 
Try to go over jquery upgrade manual here: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/

From jquery upgrade guide:

> 1. Upgrade the version of jQuery on the page to the latest 1.x or 2.x version (currently 1.12.3 or 2.2.3).
> 2. Add the uncompressed [jQuery Migrate 1.x Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/tree/1.x-stable/#README)
>      to the page.
> 3. Optional but recommended, update any plugins in use since later versions are usually the most compatible with recent versions of
>      jQuery.
> 4. Test the page and resolve any warnings that appear on the console, using the [JQMIGRATE 1.x warning
>      documentation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/tree/1.x-stable/warnings.md)
>      as a guide.
> 5. Remove the jQuery Migrate 1.x plugin and ensure that the updated jQuery code on the page continues to work properly with only the
>      latest jQuery 1.x/2.x in use.
> 6. Upgrade the version of jQuery on the page to the latest 3.0 version (currently 3.0.0) and add the uncompressed [jQuery Migrate 3.x
>      plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#README) to the page.
> 7. Test the page and resolve any warnings that appear on the console, using the [JQMIGRATE 3.x warning
>      documentation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md)
>      as a guide. Report any bugs in third-party plugins to the plugin
>      author.
> 8. Remove the jQuery Migrate 3.x plugin and ensure that the page continues to work properly with only the latest jQuery 3.x in use.